# Does StackExchange.Redis supports MONITOR?

Tags: redis, stackexchange.redis

I recently migrated from Booksleeve to StackExchange.Redis.

For monitoring purposes, I need to use the [MONITOR](http://redis.io/commands/monitor) command.

In the [wiki](https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.Redis/blob/master/Docs/Basics.md) I read

> From the IServer instance, the Server commands are available

But I can't find any method concerning MONITOR in `IServer` ; After a quick search in the repository, it seems this command is not mappped even if `RedisCommand.MONITOR` is defined.

So, is the MONITOR command supported by StackExchange.Redis ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Support for monitor is not provided, for multiple reasons:

- invoking `monitor` is a path with of no return; a `monitor` connection can never be anything *except* a `monitor` connection - it certainly doesn't play nicely with the multiplexer (although I guess a separate connection could be used)
- `monitor` is not something that is generally encouraged - it has impact; and when you *do* use it, it would be a good idea to run it *as close to the server as possible* (typically in a terminal to the server itself)
- it should typically be used for short durations

But more importantly, perhaps, I *simply haven't seen a suitable user-case or had a request for it*. If there is some scenario where `monitor` makes sense, I'm happy to consider adding some kind of support. What is it that you want to do with it here?

Note that caveat on the `monitor` page you link to:

> In this particular case, running a single MONITOR client can reduce the throughput by more than 50%. Running more MONITOR clients will reduce throughput even more.

Comment: that's very pertinent. My use case is not a so good reason : I just need to track all commands send to a redis DB during integration tests mainly for troubleshooting. I certainly fell into the StackExchange.Redis-everywhere problem. A basic solution may be to use a wrapper over redis-cli. By the way, many monitoring tools uses the command to compute command statistics. That's the only prod use case that I can imagine now.

Comment: @Cybermaxs I don't know if it will help you, but the test rig for SE.Redis includes a special build that lets you echo the output stream to a file - so you get a hard copy of everything that was sent on a connection. Normally it is used for internal debugging purposes, and it requires compiler symbols, but... it works!